# Why can't I see the commit hash of my application in a post-build event?

Tags: git, post-build-event

When I go to the build directory of my application, and I ask for the commit hash, everything is working fine:

```
Prompt>git log -1 --format=format:"%H"
c03245bcdf6ddd7b54af4c70d9012e16a6c8c64f
```

When I try this in a post-build event (Visual Studio, C# application), this does not work:

Post-build event:

```
git log -1 --format=format:"%H" >Release_Note2.txt
```

Contents of the file "Release_Note2.txt:

```
H
```

(indeed, just one single letter)

Does anybody know what I can do in order to get the commit hash of my application in a post-build event of my application?

I'm working on a Windows machine.

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD` will print the current commit ID your HEAD is pointing to. You can substitute `HEAD` with any tag or branch you'd like to know as well. (And also `@` in most shells is a shorthand for `HEAD`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current commit:

`git rev-parse HEAD`

That will print the current commit ID your `HEAD` is pointing to. You can substitute `HEAD` with any tag or branch you'd like to know as well. (And also `@` in most shells is a shorthand for `HEAD`.)

As for *why* your attempt didn't work, my guess is that maybe your string needs to be escaped inside of your C# application, e.g.:

`git log -1 --format=format:\"%H\" >Release_Note2.txt`

Though, if you switch to the preferred `rev-parse` command perhaps you don't need to worry about why.

Comment: If the git command is formed using something like `printf()`, then a literal `%H` would be an invalid conversion specifier and cause undefined behavior (which _might_ including printing just `H` in the command string). In that case the fix would be to use `%%H` instead of just `%H` in the format string. Edit: But I agree that `rev-parse` is the better solution.